# Conference registerer

Tags: single-word-requests

Maybe this is a Stackoverflow question, but I am not sure. I am looking for a word(or perhaps a phrase) to describe a person who registers for a lot of conferences but never bothers to attend them.

There are so many conferences in and around London, and I know a bunch of people who almost always register for *all* of these conferences but don't bother to attend these. How do I describe them or their behaviour?

Comment: A 'non-shower'?

Comment: I've heard people say the phrase: "we have a couple of no-shows today at the conference". Not sure if it is gramatically correct though.

Answer (score 4):

I’m not aware of any "official" term for this, but you could use ***phantom registrants***.

*Phantom* can be used as an adjective to mean *illusive, fictitious, nonexistent, existing in perception only*.

Sometimes, *phantom* has a negative connotation, implying some measure of deliberate trickery (*phantom voters, phantom employees*). In this case, I doubt *phantom registrants* are trying to bolster numbers or deceive conference organizers, but it wouldn't surprise me to learn of some deleterious effects nonetheless (such as ordering more conference materials than are needed, etc.)

Comment: "phantom registrants" conjures up an image of dead registrants whose souls are attending a long forgotten conference. :) It has an ethereal quality to it, I'd say.

Comment: @Anup: Yup; if we shorten _phantom registrants_ to just plain _phantoms_, then we definitely run the risk of conjuring some eerie images at the conference (which is why I recommend using it as an [adjective](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/phantom)). I wondered if that definition of the word might come back to haunt me ;^)

Comment: *oooOOOOoooh!*  +1.  :)